# Improve performance on Python object comparison

Tags: python, performance

Why is this comparison so slow? For about 100k calls (according to the profiler) it takes tens of seconds to complete. I'm a Python noob so I'm not sure if this is the expected performance. Can I speed the comparison up?

```
def is_obj_in(list, obj):
    for i in list:
        if i["rowid"] == obj["rowid"] \
                and i["tid"] == obj["tid"] \
                and i["cid"] == obj["cid"] \
                and i["text"] == obj["text"]:
            return True
    return False
```

**EDIT**

I've created an example, but that tuns way faster. So I guess the problem is not in the comparison (or my test code is at fault).

```
def create_test_data(n):
    data = []
    for i in range(n):
        data.append({"rowid": str(i),
                     "uid": str(i),
                     "tid": str(i),
                     "cid": str(i),
                     "text": str(i)})
    return data


def is_obj_in(target_list, obj):
    for i in target_list:
        if i["rowid"] == obj["rowid"] \
                and i["tid"] == obj["tid"] \
                and i["cid"] == obj["cid"] \
                and i["text"] == obj["text"]:
            return True
    return False


target_data = create_test_data(100)
test_data = create_test_data(100000)
within = []
out = []
for td in test_data:
    if is_obj_in(target_data, td):
        within.append(td)
    else:
        out.append(td)
print(len(within))
print(len(out))
```

Comment: how many items in the `list` ? 100K calls in 10 seconds, means each comparison takes around 100 micro seconds (10K per second). That is pretty good for a python function, so I can only assume that the list is reasonably short.

To improve it you could store the hash value of the object, and then compare the hash values first - if the hash values are different the objects must be different. If the hash values are the same then compare the fields.

Btw it is a really really bad idea to use the name `list` as a parameter name.

Comment: This looks like the job for a set, not a list. An [mcve] would help, though.

Comment: To store the hash, is it enough to create a class for the "obj" dictionary and implement the __hash__ function?

Comment: @OndrejSotolar  - that would work, although I would write the `__hash__` function so that it looks for a cached version, Also iff you are going to the hassle of writing a new class, then write a `__eq__` method too, so that your code looks nicer - with a `__eq__` method you could write `if obj in the_list`, since the in operator will use `__eq__` under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can turn your target_data into a set of keys, the process should go about 5 times faster (for this example):

```
# get a hashable key out of the object
def dataKey(obj): return tuple(obj[k] for k in ("rowid","tid","cid","text"))

within = []
out    = []
targetSet = set(map(dataKey,target_data)) # turn the list into a set
for td in test_data:
    if dataKey(td) in targetSet:  # set inclusion is O(1)
        within.append(td)
    else:
        out.append(td)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_obj_in(list, obj):
    important_keys = ["rowid", "tid", "cid", "text"]

    for i in list:
        comparison_obj = dict([(key, i[key]) for key in important_keys])
        if obj == comparison_obj:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Did you time/profile this? It is doing significantly more, creating several temporary objects  - it should be significantly slower than the original.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is even worse performance-wise :)

Comment: Didn't try it sorry, actually the important keys can be outside of the function and there is no need to create the comparison_obj variable

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, your comparisons will be faster if you can convert your dicts into a hashable object. These appear to be strings that follow some rules about what characters can be in them (e.g., a TID may just be hex digits) so you could pick a character disallowed in any but the `text` field, and join them. Put these targets in a set and now your list enumeration and dictionary compare are just checking membership in the set. Here is a reworking of your test to show the original, updated and (just for fun) a cython version. On my machine the test run was

```
Test on 100 X 100000
original
within 100, out 99900: delta 0.45616527699894505
compare as strings
within 100, out 99900: delta 0.029960855004901532
compare as strings with cython
within 100, out 99900: delta 0.017779971996787935
```

test.py

```
from time import perf_counter

def create_test_data(n):
    data = []
    for i in range(n):
        data.append({"rowid": str(i),
                     "uid": str(i),
                     "tid": str(i),
                     "cid": str(i),
                     "text": str(i)})
    return data

target_data = create_test_data(100)
test_data = create_test_data(100000)
print(f"Test on {len(target_data)} X {len(test_data)}")

def test(algorithm, target_data, test_data):
    start = perf_counter()
    within = []
    out = []
    for td in test_data:
        if algorithm(target_data, td):
            within.append(td)
        else:
            out.append(td)
    delta = perf_counter() - start
    return within, out, delta

def is_obj_in(target_list, obj):
    for i in target_list:
        if i["rowid"] == obj["rowid"] \
                and i["tid"] == obj["tid"] \
                and i["cid"] == obj["cid"] \
                and i["text"] == obj["text"]:
            return True
    return False

print("original")
within, out, delta = test(is_obj_in, target_data, test_data)
print(f"within {len(within)}, out {len(out)}: delta {delta}")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# convert to a set of strings for comparison
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def _data_to_str(data):
    return "|".join((data["rowid"], data["tid"], data["cid"], data["text"])) 

def test2(target_data, test_data):
    start = perf_counter()
    target_set = {_data_to_str(d) for d in target_data}
    within = []
    out = []
    for data in test_data:
        if _data_to_str(data) in target_set:
            within.append(data)
        else:
            out.append(data)
    delta = perf_counter() - start
    return within, out, delta

print("compare as strings")
within, out, delta = test2(target_data, test_data)
print(f"within {len(within)}, out {len(out)}: delta {delta}")

try:
    from ctest import test3
    print("compare as strings with cython")
    within, out, delta = test3(target_data, test_data)
    print(f"within {len(within)}, out {len(out)}: delta {delta}")
except ImportError:
    print("don't have the cython version")
```

ctest.pyx

```
from time import perf_counter

cdef str _data_to_str(dict d):
    return "|".join((d["rowid"], d["tid"], d["cid"], d["text"]))

cpdef tuple test3(list target_data, list test_data):
    cdef float start = perf_counter()
    cdef set target_set = {_data_to_str(d) for d in target_data}
    cdef list within = []
    cdef list out = []
    cdef dict data
    for data in test_data:
        if _data_to_str(data) in target_set:
            within.append(data)
        else:
            out.append(data)
    delta = perf_counter() - start
    return within, out, delta
```